# @objc' can only be applied to an extension of a class , calling extension method from swift to objective c

Tags: swift, extension-methods

I am creating string extension like

```
@objc extension String {
static func className(_ aClass: AnyClass) -> String {
    return NSStringFromClass(aClass).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
}
    func localize() -> String
{
    return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
}}
```

I am using this in swift like

```
btnReferencePhoto.setTitle("ADD REFERENCE PHOTO".localize(), for: .normal)
```

I want to use it in objective c 
but I am able to access localize method in objective c file 
for that I add @objc  in string extension, but it is giving error

[image]

I also tried

[image]

Comment: The error is clear. Remember, `String` is a struct, not a class.

Comment: so how to call it in objective c class ..do u have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `String` in Objective-C. Swift structs can't be used in Objective-C.

One solution is to mirror your String extension in an extension to NSString.

```
extension String {
    static func className(_ aClass: AnyClass) -> String {
        return NSStringFromClass(aClass).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    }

    func localize() -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }
}

@objc extension NSString {
    static func className(_ aClass: AnyClass) -> NSString {
        let res = String.className(aClass)

        return res as NSString
    }

    func localize() -> NSString {
        let str = self as String

        return str.localize() as NSString
    }
}
```

The NSString extension calls the String extension implementation so you are not replicating the functionality, just the API.

Now in your Objective-C code you can do something like:

```
NSString *name = [NSString className:[SomeObjectiveCClass class]];
NSLog(@"name = %@", name);

NSString *localized = [@"test" localize];
```

Comment: yeap, using NSString return type instead of String, did the trick for me. Thanks